# How to Prevent Double Forward Slash From Being Encoded?

Tags: rest-assured

I'm making a get request to something similar to the following:
https://endpoint.com/path/to/what//want?param=value

I'm intentionally missing a value in between 'what' and 'want' to test that it gives a 404 error.
The problem is that for some reason it gets encoded before hand and what is being sent through is:
https://endpoint.com/path/to/what%2f%2fwant?param=value

Which causes a 400 to be returned because this is just a bad request.

I know I can turn encoding off but sometimes the param/value combination will need to be encoded so I would like to avoid doing that.

I've tried forming the connection string using plain concatenation and StringBuilder but that made no difference.

Any tips or others things to attempt to try would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only option is to disable URL encoding using:

```
given().urlEncoding(false). ..
```

and then URL encode the parts you wish to url encode manually. REST Assured can't always guess correctly and this is such as case.

Comment: Yeah I figured and that's what I'm doing right now.
I just don't get why it thinks the double slash needs to be encoded. I guess I could add a space in between to prevent it.

Comment: It's a good question and I can't give you a good answer. In my mind it might be a bug (so feel free to contribute :))