# Java Rest Assured is over processing my get request

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to connect to a REST API (Not my own so I can't fix their issues) but when I send a GET request, Rest Assured is reprocessing my URI causing the call to fail.

Here is the code to build the request:

```
Call rest = new Call("https://rest.test.com"); // Custom class to simplify REST calls.

JSONObject searchCriteria = new JSONObject();
searchCriteria.put("textSearchType", "SEARCHNAME");
searchCriteria.put("textSearchString", "joe blow");

String header = "Lead Inline Quick Search";

StringBuilder resource = new StringBuilder("/api/v1/search?");
resource.append("searchCriteria=")
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(searchCriteria.toString()))
        .append("&header=")
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(header));

System.out.println("REST call: " + resource.toString());

rest.get(resource.toString(), 200); // Perform a get on the query, expect a 200 response
```

When I look at the output, the request is correct:

```
REST call: /api/v1/search?searchCriteria=%7B%22textSearchString%22%3A%22joe+blow%22%2C%22textSearchType%22%3A%22SEARCHNAME%22%7D&header=Lead+Inline+Quick+Search
```

However when I look at the debug for Rest Assured, it reprocesses the request causing the call to fail:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI: https://rest.test.com/api/v1/search?searchCriteria=%257B%2522textSearchString%2522%253A%2522joe%2Bblow%2522%252C%2522textSearchType%2522%253A%2522SEARCHNAME%2522%257D&header=Lead%2BInline%2BQuick%2BSearch
```

Note:

- '{' is correctly converted to '%7B' from the Net encoding and looks right in the `resource`, but Rest Assured then further converts all the '%' to '%25' making the json invalid ({ becomes %257B).
- The '+' in the header is converted to '%20' for some reason. While technically the same, there is no reason to "fix" it.

If I don't encode the values when building the resource, the get call fails because it sees the spaces.

```
IllegalArgumentException-Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0. Undefined path parameters are: "textSearchString":"joe blow","textSearchType":"SEARCHNAME".
```

So what is the proper way to encode the values? Or get Rest Assured not to monkey with the string it's sent?

Comment: Have you tried turning off the URL encoding on Rest Assured? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399627/how-to-prevent-double-forward-slash-from-being-encoded

Comment: @Hypino, tried adding `.urlEncodingEnabled(false)` and it did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @Hypino put me on the right track.

Adding `.urlEncodingEnabled(false)` to the `.given()` did not change the results (call was still double processed). But adding `.setUrlEncodingEnabled(false)` to the `RequestSpecBuilder()` gave the correct results.

```
private RequestSpecBuilder build = new RequestSpecBuilder().setUrlEncodingEnabled(false);
```

The logged call and the actual call are now the same:

```
REST call: /api/v1/search?searchCriteria=%7B%22textSearchString%22%3A%22joe+blow%22%2C%22textSearchType%22%3A%22SEARCHNAME%22%7D&header=Lead+Inline+Quick+Search

Request method: GET
Request URI: https://rest.test.com/api/v1/search?searchCriteria=%7B%22textSearchString%22%3A%22joe+blow%22%2C%22textSearchType%22%3A%22SEARCHNAME%22%7D&header=Lead+Inline+Quick+Search
```